# How to match the symbol "." with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm doing a windows form application to search words in a file but I  have a problem to match the symbol "." ,  the pattern of Regex is set from a textbox, but whenever i type "." it matches the whole text in the  content of the file. I want to match only the symbol "."  so what should I do ?

Comment: Have you tried escaping it with "\" ?

Comment: Please do some research on regular expressions before posting. Googling « regex match dot » gets your answer in the first result...

Answer (score 7):

Escape it with a `\`:

```
Regex.Match(textBox.Text, @"\.");
```

> "\" Marks the next character as either a special character or escapes a literal. For example, "n" matches the character "n". "\n" matches a newline character. The sequence "\\" matches "\" and "\(" matches "(".

[Source](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet)

Comment: the OP doesn't want to search for `"."` in the textbox "Text". They want to use the `Text` to search in a file.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\.` in your pattern string.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, call [`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) on the `string`. to handle the other situations you've overlooked.

Whilst the other answers (so far) explan how to escape `"."`, this method will handle all the other potential snags, like the escape character `"\"` itself.

Comment: In my opinion, this isn't proper programming. I think the user itself should be able to write a valid regex without having to rely on external tools to do it for him.

Comment: "External tools" is a kind of a harsh term. `Regex.Escape` is part of the .NET framework. If the base framework offers some methods to make your life easier, why not use them?

Comment: @ChaotiCc, I like to keep DRY. What would be the "proper" alternative for escaping a user entered string.

Comment: I forgot we were talking about user-entered strings here, my apologies. @Otiel, I just think that the more you automate things, the less people will understand the underlying concepts, which is in my opinion an important thing.

Comment: @ChaotiCc, agreed its also important to remember the law of leaky abstractions. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html

Answer (score 0):

Regex uses the '\' char to allow special chars.

Take a [look at this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) for more information:

Answer (score 0):

In regex `'.'` has a special meaning - to match anything! Try escaping it like `\.` in your expression.

```
MatchCollection match = Regex.Matches(entireText, @"alphabet\.");
```

Answer (score 0):

In regular expressions, `.` is a special character matching any character. To match a dot, you should escape it with a backslash (`\`). The same goes for other reserved characters, like `$`, `(`, `)`, `[`, `]` and `^`.

So, you regex should be `\.` and not just `.`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **Regex.Escape(".")**, 
Try this and this can be used for all other symbols for escaping such as [ , ] , \ etc.